# JavaFX How to drag and drop an image

Tags: java, javafx

I am making a card game in JavaFX and what I was able to find code that will allow me to drag a piece of text. However, this doesn't show the text being dragged.

What I am currently doing is setting my scene which is the root node to be the target and setting my cards to be the source. This allows me to drag cards which are image views on my desktop but I want two things which I am struggling with.

First I want to have the image actually show up when I am dragging it and second I want to be able to place the image on my scene.

Here is the code for the card

```
        tempImageView.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                /* drag was detected, start a drag-and-drop gesture*/
                /* allow any transfer mode */
                Dragboard db = 
 tempImageView.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

                /* Put a string on a dragboard */
                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                content.putData(tempImageView);
                db.setContent(content);

                event.consume();
            }
        });
```

Here is the code for my scene

```
    scene.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            /* data is dragged over the target */
            /* accept it only if it is not dragged from the same node 
             * and if it has a string data */
            /* allow for both copying and moving, whatever user chooses */
            event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
            event.consume();
        }
    });
```

Here is the tutorial I was trying to follow: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/jfxpub-drag_drop.htm

I am new to JavaFX so any help would be awesome!

Comment: What you are asking is quite complex and involves many steps, and more than one question. If you want to see the "card" when you move it, then you need to create a new component on a glass pane that will render and move the image/card according to mouse location. To place the image you need to register the drop co-ordinates and then do some math to work out where to place it in the scene (Will require thinking about how you lay out your application, and how you store your cards, and how you can snap a card to a location).

Comment: How would I go about just dropping an image at a specic locaion like drag the image and drop i somewhere on a scene

Comment: You don't. You instead create a new component at the mouse drop location, or you move the existing component that had the card to that new drop location. The image that you see when you drag an item should only be an image that simulates a drag action, but it is not actually the real card. It will require a bit of thinking and logic to get it looking just right for your application.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try it out

Comment: You appear to be putting the `ImageView` in the `CliboardContent`. This likely won't work as expected. You should be putting the actual `Image` from the `ImageView` into the content (e.g. `content.putImage(tempImageView.getImage())`). If you look at [the documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/ClipboardContent.html#putImage(javafx.scene.image.Image)) of `putImage` you'll see that that image will become the drag view. Otherwise, you can set the drag view manually with `Dragboard.setDragView`.